# JAX-WS standalone server mutual authentication through certificates

Tags: web-services, ssl, certificate, jax-ws, mutual-authentication

I have a simple JAX-WS standalone server which is using TLS:

```
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
store.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), keyPass.toCharArray()); 

kmf.init(store, keyPass.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[1];
keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(store);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
ssl.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(ssl);
HttpsServer httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8443), 8443);
httpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);   

HttpContext context = httpsServer.createContext("/test");
httpsServer.start();

endpoint.publish(context);
```

I would like to use client certificates to create mutual authentication before using web services. Also I would like to see what certificate was used by the client to read DN and other certificate attributes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

Mutual authentication can be configured through `setNeedClientAuth` in `SSLParameters` like the following:

```
HttpsConfigurator configurator=new HttpsConfigurator(ssl) {
    public void configure (HttpsParameters params) 
            {
                SSLContext context; 
                SSLParameters sslparams;

                context=getSSLContext();
                sslparams=context.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                sslparams.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
            }
        };
```

And the client certificate can be checked and parsed according needs from `SSLSession`. This class can be loaded as resource in web service class:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

HttpsExchange exchange = (HttpsExchange) context.getMessageContext().get(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_EXCHANGE);
SSLSession sslsession = exchange.getSSLSession();

sslsession.getPeerCertificates();
```